# C++ linux install executable file on deploy environment

Tags: c++, linux, deployment, makefile, installation

Hello every one i need to deploy linux(centos) c++ project with make file or script. By one makefile or script install dependency and project executable binary.
my dependency applications libboost-devel,gcc-g++ and pcre. my excuteble binary file is run_excute

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: @Karsten Koop  sample or example of makefile or script to deploy on linux machine my project.

Comment: @Karsten Koop  Just simply  install my project binary file run_excute using make file or script. can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yip sure - put the below commands into a file. At the top of the file add:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Save the file - lets say you call it install; on the command line type:

```
chmod +x ./install
```

Then to build and install your program type:

```
sudo ./install
```

Alternatively, if you've got some time on your hands: 
    http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-build.html

---

As an example the basic rpm build process for fedora is:

Step 1: setup your machine to do packaging:

```
dnf install @development-tools fedora-packager rpmdevtools
rpmdev-setuptree
```

Step 2: source and Makefile
Place these in ~/rpmbuild/SOURCES

Step 3: Create a spec file
In ~/rpmbuild/SPECS create file called myname.spec.  It should contain something like:

```
Summary:            My program description
Name:               myname
Version:            0.0.0
Release:            0
License:            GPLv2
Group:              Applications/Databases
Source:             https://xyz.tar.gz
URL:                http://myurl
BuildRequires:      libicu-devel
BuildRequires:      pcre-devel

%description
A couple of lines describing the package

%prep
%setup -q

%build
cd %{myname}/source
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
%make_install

%files
%{_bindir}/*

%changelog
* Tue Nov 10 2015 Yours Truly <me@somewhere.com> - 0.0.0-0
- Some change comments
```

Step 4: create the source and binary rpm

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS
rpmbuild -ba myname.spec
```

Step 5: use the rpm

```
cd ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64
rpm -Uvh ./myprogram-version-release.a.whole.lot.of.stuff.rpm
```

Comment: @ myk thank you for your response building rpm is good point can you show me with simple example building rpm to my c++ project. please show me with simple example

Comment: @ myk if I follow this step is it create installation for my c++ project?

Comment: Yes: these steps will allow you to create a file with a .rpm at the end of the file name, which is kinda like a windows install.exe file, but .rpm files are  for RHEL and Fedora linux distributions.  So you could distribute just the .rpm file.  To unpack (install) you program you would use the rpm -Uvh command.  There is no need to compile the program when you install it, because the .rpm file contains your program already compiled.

Answer (score 0):

To install the dependencies use yum, so:

```
sudo yum install libboost-devel
sudo yum group install "Development Tools"
sudo yum install pcre-devel
```

To build the application, move to the directory with the makefile in it and do:

```
make
sudo make install
```

Finally to run the application

```
./run_excute
```

or if your lucky

```
run_excute
```

will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response this is not my question can i make installer for my c++ project with binary file run_excute